# Is there anything wrong with a python infinite loop and time.sleep()?

Tags: python, time, infinite-loop

I had a program that ran recursively, and while 95% of the time it wasn't an issue sometimes I would hit a recursion limit if I was doing something that took too long. In my efforts to convert to and iterative code, I decided to try something along the lines of this:

```
while True:
    do something

    #check if task is done
    if done:
        print 'ALL DONE'
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(600)
        continue
```

I've tested my code and it works fine, but I was wondering if there is anything inherently wrong with this method? Will it eat up RAM or crash the box if it was left to run for too long?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The "do something" I refer to is checking a log file for certain keywords periodically, as data is constantly being written to the log file. Once these lines are written, which happens at varying length of times, I have the script perform certain tasks, such as copying specific lines to a separate files.

My original program had two functions, one called itself periodically until it found keywords, which would then call the 'dosomething' function. The do something function upon completion would then call original function, and this would happen until the task was finished or I hit the recursion limit

Comment: What's it doing? Depending on what you're doing, there may or may not be a better way. It looks like you're waiting for something to finish, in which case there may be an interface for your code to automatically wait until it finishes without constantly checking the progress.

Comment: What do you hope to gain by sleeping rather than immediately going back through the loop?

Comment: @jwodder that would eat up CPU time without any reason.

Comment: just what is `do something`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong in this pattern.  I have used the daemon function in init.d to start a very similar python script.  As long as "do something" doesn't leak, it should be able to run forever.

Answer (score 2):

I think that either way

```
 time.sleep()
```

will not stop the recursion limit
Because sleep only pauses the execution , and doesn't free any kind of memory 
check https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html the Time.sleep() description

It suspends the operation , but it will not do any memory optimization

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you describe is easy to implement, but usually not the best way to do things.  If the task completes just after you check, you still have to wait 5 minutes to resume processing.  However, sometimes there is little choice but to do this; for example, if the only way to detect the task is complete is to check for the existence of a file, you may have to do it this way.  In such cases the time interval choice needs to balance the CPU consumed by the "spin" with wait time.

Another pattern that is also fairly easy is to simply block while waiting on the task to complete.  Whether this is easy or not depends on the particular API you are using.  But this technique does not scale because all processing must wait for a single activity to complete.  Imagine not being able to open a new browser tab while a page is loading.

Best practice today generally uses one of several models for asynchronous processing.  Much like writing event handlers for mouse clicks, etc. in a website or GUI, you write a callback function that handles the result of processing, and pass that callback to the task.  No CPU is wasted and the response is handled immediately without waiting.  Many frameworks support this model today.  [Tulip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tulip) uses the actor model.

Specifically regarding the recursion limit, I don't think your sleep loop is responsible for hitting the stack frame limit.  Maybe it was something happening within the task itself.